Ground Switching Relay, 400A
Can a three pole Contactor Relay be used for simply switching Ground? I am trying to reverse the polarity of a welding unit and would need to be able to command essentially two relays to open and close on a 42V signal. I can not find a general relay for this size that has that current rating. The ground will have 400 A AC current flowing through it. The devices that I am finding for that current rating are for switching three phase power.

Usually the term for a unit of that capacity is "contactor", and yeah, they won't be cheap.  Are you sure what you're planning to do is the best way to do it? Or is recommended and safe to do?

Yes, we are working with the power supply company. They sent a recommendation for a three phase contactor. I was wondering if we can go for a lower contact rating, as we could run the ground in parallel to theoretically triple our current rating through parallel distribution. Otherwise I will order a contactor rated for 400A

The contacts are rated for switching resistive current and derated for low pf.   Are you reversing with current  ON or OFF?

Essentially there is our machine power which is different than the welding ground. This is the ground that carries the variable current to the weld torch. We are using a MIG and TIG machine. We want to automatically switch from MIG to TIG without removing the cables from the machine through a relay. This relay will simply unplug our welding ground for us and plug in the other. I have yet to find a contactor/ relay that runs N/O and N/C for this level of Current. So I will need to get one for each ground cable.

so no power during switching DPDT .

DAS yes exactly.

then like this   https://www.electriccarpartscompany.com/400a-double-pole-double-throw-contactor-dc-coil

Contact ratings are driven mostly by switching. If you can guarantee less or no current flow during switching, you might get away with a lower rating, but still, reliability isn't guaranteed.
